# Why LWC is not subscribe Platform events in Production

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event

I've created simple Platform event & LWC. LWC just subscribe platform event & I'm debugging response in console. But when I publish event from developer console Nothing is happening on LWC console. But same LWC & Platform event is working fine on Sandbox environment. 
Are there any permission to give in Production to use this model???(Test_Event__e - Read Permission is already given at profile level)

Below is js I've written in LWC.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import {
    subscribe,
    unsubscribe,
    onError,
    setDebugFlag,
    isEmpEnabled,
} from 'lightning/empApi';
export default class TestForEvent extends LightningElement {
    subscription = {};
    channelName = '/event/Test_Event__e';
    connectedCallback() {
        //track your plateform event from here
        this.handleSubscribe();
        this.registerErrorListener();
    }
     //platform event
     handleSubscribe() {
        
        // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (response) => this.messageCallback(response)).then(response => {
            console.log('Subscription request sent to: '+JSON.stringify(response.channel));
            this.subscription = response;
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
    messageCallback(response){
        console.log('response '+JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    registerErrorListener() {
        // Invoke onError empApi method
        onError(error => {
            console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            // Error contains the server-side error
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What about edit permission to permisisonset/profile who is publishing the event ?